# Sending emails using loopback 3.x with default user model

Tags: node.js, loopbackjs, strongloop

I am trying to send reset password email for default loopback `User` model but it simply doesn't work. I have tried and read all possible examples I could find, none of them worked.

I have tried to follow [official documentation](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Email-connector.html) for email connector, and this is my `datasources.json`

```
"emailDs": {
    "name": "emailDs",
    "connector": "mail",
    "transports": [
      {
        "type": "smtp",
        "host": "smtp.gmail.com",
        "secure": true,
        "port": 465,
        "auth": {
          "user": "myemail@gmail.com",
          "pass": "password"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
```

for `model-config.json` I have this

```
...
"Role": {
    "dataSource": "db",
    "public": false
  },
  "Email": {
    "dataSource": "emailDs"
  },
  "user": {
    "dataSource": "db",
    "public": true,
    "options": {}
  }
```

As you may see in this file, I have also created a new model called `user` (no capital U, which extends default `User` model. I simply copied the code for this user from [this example](https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-example-user-management) (scroll down for user password reset).

I registered new `user` model so I can see it in `domain.com:3000/explorer/` .. So I have `user` and `User` models.

I have also created a file in `/boot/routes.js` and pasted all code from the example linked above.

Now since I have email datasource set up in `datasources.json` it should work, or not? Because I tried to post a password reset using `/Users/reset` which requires only email in this form (probably)

`{
"email":"myuseraccount@email.com"
}`

which is email of a user, which is already registered. Just to mention, I am working on android app, registration and sign in work fine. So I hit `Try it out` button to execute reset password request, I get `204 Request was successful` but I get no email. Even node console doesn't show any errors, only when I enter email, which is not in database of registered users, ..

For my gmail email configuration (email which should send reset pass email to users), I enabled access for less secure apps in Gmail account, I have also tried to enable 2-step verification and created an account for an app, where gmail gave me unique password only for this app. I have used this password and put it in `datasources.json` and that password was never used to login, so it means that loopback never executes `send` function to send that reset pass email, which is totally frustrating!

Any idea how to set it up properly for that default user?
Btw, I have tried to send pass request from both models, `User` and `user` and none of them worked....

**//Update**

I have traced that when I send request with email (using postman for example), function `User.resetPassword = function(options, cb) { .. }` in default `User` model `user.js` is executed. But what should follow next? Calling `send email` somewhere, but how and where? I tried to understand documentation, but its very complex to understand.

**//Update 2**
Even though official documentation says not to edit default `User` model, I edited it.

I have added sending function and now it is finally sending email:

```
//send password reset link when requested
User.on('resetPasswordRequest', function(info) {
    var url = 'http://mywebsite.com:3000/api/Users/reset-password';
    var html = 'Click <a href="' + url + '?access_token=' +
        info.accessToken.id + '">here</a> to reset your password';

    User.app.models.Email.send({
        to: info.email,
        from: null,
        subject: 'Password reset',
        html: html
    }, function(err) {
        if (err) return console.log('> error sending password reset email');
        console.log('> sending password reset email to:', info.email);
    });
});
```

Problem is that the reset password doesnt work, because when I get the email, I click on the URL, and all I get is `401 Unauthorized access` and after a while, it says `Invalid token` , I suppose it has some expiration time.

Comment: did you also set it in `model-config.json` file?

Comment: If you read my question, I have `model-config.json` content provided.. I got it to work somehow but its not a proper way to do it, and I want to do it right. I will update question.